# delete button want to stop process after click cancel from confirm alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

now the website can extract api's data, and show on table, and also can delete the table's row by clicking the button

[(pic) table and alert showing up after click delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr0Al.png)

Q: If I click cancel from the alert, the delete process wouldn't stop, how can I correct the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/item",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
            return response.ipcs
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" },
          { data: "updated_at", title: "updated_at" }
        ]
      });

      // Edit row function (not done yet)
      $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        editRow(id);
      });



///// below is how delete button work   ///// 
      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {  
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        
        console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)
        deleteData(id)
        deleteRow(id) 
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/item/?device_id="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }
///// above is how delete button work  ///// 

      function editRow(id) {
        // TODO: Implement editRow logic
        console.log("Edit row with id:", id);
      }

      function deleteRow(id) {
        if (confirm("are you sure delete this row？")) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ps. I also working on edit button too, later on need to make that edit function work

Comment: You are calling `deleteData(id)`, which will make the request to delete the data, _before_ you even called any confirm dialog (that only happens in `deleteRow`, which you are calling _afterwards_.)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @CBroe's advice, other wise, as a starter I really don't know where the problem is. Now I get the right one

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {  
  var id = $(this).data('id')
        
  console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)

  deleteRow(id) 
});

function deleteData(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "192.168.10.01:8000/api/item?device_id="+ id,
    type:'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
}

function editRow(id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "192.168.10.01:8000/api/item/?device_id="+ id,
    type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
}

function deleteRow(id) {
  if (confirm("are you sure delete this row？") == true) {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable();
    var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
    deleteData(id);

    if (row.length > 0) {
      row.remove().draw();
      console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
    }
  } else {
    none
  }
}
});
```